# MyST allowing non-consecutive header level increase

Tags: markdown, python-sphinx, myst

I want to generate pages with a large header at the top but much smaller headers below. So for example

```
<h1> Big heading </h1>
Test

<h4> Small heading </h4>
test
```

But if I go immediately from `# Big Heading` to `#### Small heading` I get this warning:

> WARNING: Non-consecutive header level increase; H1 to H4 [myst.header]

and it actually uses h1 and h2. If I start with say `###` and then use `####` it starts with h1.

Is there any way to avoid having the subheadings being so large?

Comment: Use a custom style to change the display size of the lesser level headings.

Comment: Thanks. I found out how to change the style across the entire Sphinx website, but I want to change it only for a subset of my pages (in my case the manual pages) but not the rest of the site.  Is there a way to provide a customization that only affects some of the pages?

Comment: Styling headers differently across pages could be done editing the template to wrap all the content with a div with an id only for certain pages, and using that for the selector to style headings only on those pages. The tricky part would be "only for certain pages", but I imagine you could write a Python function to detect the current page and return true/false which could be interpreted by the template to render the div with a special id or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `suppress_warnings = ["myst.header"]` to your `conf.py` to disable this check but it will have an effect on entire docs.